# Armadillo & Codeblocks on windows

Tags: c++, windows, codeblocks, linker-errors, armadillo

I am having significant trouble getting Armadillo 5.000.1 to work with CodeBlocks 13.12 on Windows 8.1.

---

- In `project build options -> linker settings` I've added the libraries `..\armadillo-5.000.1\examples\lib_win64\blas_win64_MT.lib` and `..\armadillo-5.000.1\examples\lib_win64\lapack_win64_MT.lib`.
- In `project build options->search directories` I've added `..\armadillo-5.000.1\include` and `..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-4.9.2-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev2\mingw64\include` to compiler and `..\armadillo-5.000.1\examples\lib_win64` to linker.
- I've uncommented `#define ARMA_USE_LAPACK` and `#define ARMA_USE_BLAS` in `config.hpp`.
- I am (I think) using a 64 bit mingw compiler.

---

When I run the example1.cpp file, I obtain the following error:

```
-------------- Build: Debug in CS156b (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

g++.exe -L..\armadillo-5.000.1\examples\lib_win64 -o bin\Debug\CS156b.exe obj\Debug\armadillo-5.000.1\examples\example1.o obj\Debug\load_data3.o   ..\armadillo-5.000.1\examples\lib_win64\lapack_win64_MT.lib ..\armadillo-5.000.1\examples\lib_win64\blas_win64_MT.lib
..\armadillo-5.000.1\examples\lib_win64\lapack_win64_MT.lib: error adding symbols: File format not recognized
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Also, the code my teammate wrote and which runs fine on her (Linux) computer

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>
#define ARMA_64BIT_WORD
#include <armadillo>

/*
 * Read in data from the um.zip file all.dta
 * and store in a sparse vector. There are
 * 458293 reviewers and 17770 reviews.
 */

int main()
{
using namespace std;
clock_t begin = clock();

vector<double> ratings;
arma::umat locations = arma::umat(2, 102416306);

// Open the file
string line;
ifstream myfile("um/all.dta");
int c = 0;
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while (getline(myfile, line))
    {
        //cout << line << endl;
        if (c % 100 == 0)
            cout << c<< endl;


        int space1 = line.find(" ");
        int space2 = line.find(" ", space1 + 1);
        int space3 = line.find(" ", space2 + 1);

        // Insert into our temporary data vectors
        locations(0, c) = atoi(line.substr(0, space1).c_str());
        locations(1, c) = atoi(line.substr(space1 + 1, space2).c_str());
        ratings.push_back(atoi(line.substr(space3 + 1).c_str()));
        // cout << user << " " << review << " " << rating << endl;
        /*
        boost::split(split_line, line, boost::is_any_of(" "));

        // Convert data to ints
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < split_line.size(); ++i)
        {
            line_data.push_back(atoi(split_line[i].c_str()));
        }
        */

        c += 1;


    }
}

// Create the sparse matrix
arma::sp_mat m = arma::sp_mat(locations, arma::vec(ratings));

// Serialize the sparse matrix object
//fstream ofs("sparse_matrix_eigen");
//boost::archive::text_oarchive ar(ofs);

// Write data
//ar & m;

clock_t end = clock();
double elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
cout << elapsed_secs << endl;

cout << m;

}
```

gives me the error:

```
error: SpMat::SpMat(): number of locations is different than number of values

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  SpMat::SpMat(): number of locations is different than number of values

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

Process returned 255 (0xFF)   execution time : 5.181 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1:
I don´t know what Codeblocks is, unfortunately. But obviously the linker does not understand the lapack_win64_MT.lib file format. This has nothing to do with Armadillo. Are you running a 64bit environment? Is your linker able to read those libs which might be in Visual Studio format? I see you are using g++ here, that might be the issue.

Problem 2:
You ask a locations matrix of fixed size, but then you iterate over the length of the file. problem probably is that there are too few lines of data in the file, so the sp_mat cannot be populated properly.

```
locations = arma::umat(2, 102416306);
```

should be rather sized dynamically (example from my brain, not 100& guaranteed to work):

```
int no_of_lines;
for (no_of_lines = 0; std::getline(f, line); ++no_of_lines);
locations = arma::umat(2, no_of_lines);
```

Answer (score 1):

As a note about the code working on your teammate's box: she probably compiled without debugging symbols and with optimization, which can cause the runtime size checks to be ignored in the interest of speed (such as the one which is giving your `std::logic_error`).